# Como fazer INNER JOIN mysql

Tags: mysql

Como faço um inner join nessas tabelas:

Veiculo

- vei_id
- vei_nome
- vei_cor
- mar_id (chave estrangeira)

Marca

- mar_id
- mar_nome

Quero puxar em uma tabela vei_nome, vei_cor e mar_nome

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

Answer (score 3):

Assim:

```
SELECT Veiculo.vei_nome, Veiculo.vei_cor, Marca.mar_nome FROM Veiculo
INNER JOIN Marca ON Veiculo.mar_id = Marca.mar_id
```

Poderia também criar apelidos para suas tabelas, evitando digitação em excesso:

```
SELECT a.vei_nome, a.vei_cor, b.mar_nome FROM Veiculo a
INNER JOIN Marca b ON a.mar_id = b.mar_id
```

Na `query` acima `Veiculo` foi apelidada para `a` e `Marca` foi apelidada para `b`, então `a.mar_id` é a mesma coisa que `Veiculo.mar_id`.

Veja mais sobre [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

Comment: coloquei o código aqui, mais ele só puxou o vei_nome e o vei_cor. Não puxou o mar_nome

Comment: mar_nome esta preenchido?

Comment: sim.. tem um registro

Comment: Coloca na sua pergunta o que esta sendo retornado, e coloca também o código que você esta utilizando.

Comment: Show, eu só queria relembrar como faz o inner join e seu exemplo com os apelidos foi o mais top (claro que não cheguei olhar a documentação, mas mais claro que seu exemplo para relembrar impossível... rs). Vlw!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer o **inner join** trazendo todos os registros da tabela como também pode trazer somente o que precisa, vejamos:

**Trazendo todos os registros de ambas as tabelas**

```
SELECT * FROM Veiculo
INNER JOIN Marca ON Veiculo.mar_id = Marca.mar_id
```

Dessa forma o resultado deverá ser assim

[image: Resultado da pesquisa]

**Ou pode selecionar somente os registros de uma tabela e mais um campo**

Usando o nome da tabela **.***

```
SELECT Veiculo.*, Marca.mar_nome FROM Veiculo
INNER JOIN Marca ON Veiculo.mar_id = Marca.mar_id
```

Esses códigos foram testados no http://sqlfiddle.com

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE marca (
    mar_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    mar_nome varchar(40)
);

create table veiculo (vei_id int NOT NULL, 
  vei_nome varchar(40),
  mar_id int(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (vei_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (mar_id) REFERENCES marca(mar_id));

insert into marca values(1, 'Volkvagen');
insert into marca values(2, 'Ford');
insert into marca values(3, 'Chevrolet');


insert into veiculo values (1, 'Verona',2);
insert into veiculo values (2, 'Escort',2);
insert into veiculo values (3, 'Fusca',1);
insert into veiculo values (4, 'Caravan',3);
insert into veiculo values (5, 'Brasília',1);
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT Veiculo.*, marca.mar_nome FROM Veiculo
INNER JOIN Marca ON Veiculo.mar_id = Marca.mar_id
```