# Fazer consulta em 2 tabela

Tags: c#, sql

Não sei como fazer consulta em duas tabelas do mesmo banco.

```
tb_chamados     
id           = 1                    | 2
fkidempresa  = 47                   | 33
resumo       = descrição do chamado | descrição do chamado

tb_empresas
id           = 47                   | 33
nome         = Nome da empresa      | Nome da empresa
```

Faço uma consulta com `select * from chamados` mas o resultado vem `fkidempresa`, gostaria que retornasse o nome que está na tabela empresas e não o `fkidempresa`.

Comment: Thiago, essa pergunta ja existe, vou marca-la como duplicada. Segue a pergunta no link:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272290/como-fazer-inner-join-mysql

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT (campos)
FROM tabela1 t1 -- t1 é um alias, como se fosse um 'apelido', poderia ser qualquer nome
INNER JOIN tabela2 t2 on t1.campoReferenciado = t2.campoReferenciado
```

No seu caso seria:

```sql
select * 
from tb_chamados c
inner join tb_empresas e on e.id = c.fkidempresa
```

Para entender os tipos de joins veja [este link](http://bidescomplicado.blogspot.com/2013/10/os-tipos-de-join-quais-sao-e-como-usa.html)

---

E uma boa ilustração para representar os tipos de `join`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não aparece o nome da empresa. Em vez de colocar o * tive que colocar todos os campo descritos. "select *, tb_empresas.nome from tb_chamados c inner join tb_empresas e on e.id = c.fkidempresa" <- da erro. Mas consegui resolver.

Comment: Erro? Qual erro? O `*` serve pra selecionar todos os campos de todas as tabelas consultadas. Se desejar todos os campos de uma determinada tabela, seria `c.*` (considerando `c` o alias de uma das tabelas)

Comment: : 'Nenhum valor foi fornecido para um ou mais parâmetros necessários.'

Comment: select c.*, tb_empresas.nome from tb_chamados c inner join tb_empresas e on e.id = c.fkidempresa <- mesmo erro. Mas corrigi, digitando todos os nomes do campo.